# Attempt to mutate immutable object error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsstring, mutable

My code crashes at this line:

```
[(NSMutableString *)string replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

with the error attempt to mutate immutable object.

How is this happening and how do i fix it?

Comment: Now you're going back to reading a tutorial on typecasting in C. **Now.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The string isn't mutable, casting is not magic, it wouldn't turn it into a mutable string. You should do it on a mutable copy:

```
NSMutableString* mutableString= [string mutableCopy];
[mutableString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

Comment: +1 for "casting is not magic". I tend to say the exact same thing.

Comment: Yes, but you probably want to store the mutable version in a variable first, or it won't do you much good.

Answer (score 3):

You are typecasting an immutable string and then mutating it, actually this is not happening.

You need to create a new NSMutableString and then use `replaceCharactersInRange`...

```
NSMutableString *mutableString=[NSMutableString stringWithString:string];
[mutableString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

If you want the result in same object set it to string.

```
string=mutableString;
```